# Flutter web: how to programmatically close app (browser tab)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am creating a Flutter web app. When one of buttons is pressed I want to close browser tab when app is running. How to do that?

Comment: I am not a web developer, but I think you can't close a tab programmatically.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just like in JavaScript, you can close the window like so:

```
window.close();
```

Here's the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/WindowBase/close.html).

Comment: Chrome throws 'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.'

Comment: Not working. same issue - 'Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.'